# searching against decrypted column

Tags: postgresql, encryption, amazon-rds

I'm using Postgres on AWS RDS. My application is encrypting selected columns in a table using AWS KMS encryption. I tried but could not find a way to configure KMS keys and use the `decrypt()` in select query.

e.g. my app is encrypting `myTable.secureColumn`using KMS. now I'm trying to fire below query:

```
SELECT * 
FROM   myTable 
WHERE  decrypt(secureColumn, 'key', 'aes') = 'data';
```

I didn't find how to configure KMS keys in pgCrypto and use in above query.

Has anyone tried this?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I'd suggest taking the opposite approach: `SELECT * FROM myTable WHERE secureColumn = encrypt(data, 'key', 'aes')` if that doesn't break any security concern. Otherwise, you'll force the database to *decrypt* all rows to find the one that matches your `data`.

Comment: Thanks for the workaround. Yes your solution works if using '=' comparison operator. Need to find a way on how to use 'Like' operator. I was exploring if on the fly decrypt could be done.

Comment: It's very unusual to check for something encrypted *like* xxx. (And not what you asked for). If you need such a thing, use `LIKE ('%' || encrypt(data, 'key', 'aes') || '%')` or the expression you actually need. Use a trigram index on `secureColumn` if you need to speed up the search.

Comment: BTW: "on the fly decrypt" *can* be done, although it is very expensive. However, KMS won't give you the private key needed for decription. So, you cannot have the database decrypt something without the proper key... and that's a completely different story.